# redis-cli from docker-compose redis container doesn't catch any keys set up through Laravel

Tags: laravel, docker, redis, docker-compose, redis-cli

So when I enter the redis container with: `docker-compose exec redis bash`, I then type: `redis-cli` to start redis-cli. Then, when I try to get the key (visits) I set up through Laravel app with: `GET visits`, it shows nil.

This is how I set up the key 'visits':

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $visits = Redis::incr('visits');
    return $visits;
});
```

However, redis works fine in Laravel.
Here's my .env:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_URL=redis
REDIS_HOST=redis #172.17.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_CLIENT=phpredis
REDIS_CACHE_DB=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got it. It was persisted like this when I tried all keys:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "laravel_database_laravel_cache:aEznTaRttAEmGlOd90xQX1jtvbkVEqW7bYGFhzCR"
2) "laravel_database_visits"
```

It's because Laravel adds a prefix from database config file.